# Find same values between 2 list of dictionaries with different keys

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists of dictionaries:

```
list_1 = [{a:'cat', b:'dog', c:'bird'},{a:'**mouse**', b:'lizard', c:'fish'},{a:'**hen**', b:'pony', c:'frog'}]
list_2 = [{x:'goat', y:'**mouse**', z:'horse'},{x:'horse', y:'**hen**', z:'tiger'},{x:'bee', y:'fly', z:'toad'}]
```

The value 'mouse', and the value 'hen' are present in both list of dictionaries yet both values have unique keys.

How do find where dictionary values match between both list_1 and list_2 when in this example the keys for 'mouse' and the keys for 'hen' in both list are different?

I tried to search for similar posts and only found this comparison done with matching keys.
(example: in both lists 'hen' would have a key of 'a' and 'mouse' a value of 'c')

Comment: what do you expect the output to be here?

Comment: Any reason you are listing both [tag:python2] and [tag:python3]? Python 2 is dead, except in legacy projects.

Comment: Explain "find". Do you need to know which of the dicts contained the matching values? If so, how do you want to indicate which dict is which? Do you need to know what the corresponding keys were? Or do you just want to figure out every value that appears more than once? ... And what if a value appears in two different dicts in the *same* list?

Comment: My goal would be to find the common dictionary values between the 2 lists.
The output should be 'Hen' and 'Mouse'

Answer (score 2):

I made a function to get all the unique values for a list of dicts.

```
def unique_values_from_list(dict_list):
    all_values = set()
    for dictionary in dict_list:
        all_values.update(dictionary.values())
    return all_values
```

Using this code we can get two sets of unique values and find the intersection of these two sets:

```
list_1 = [{'a':'cat', 'b':'dog', 'c':'bird'},{'a':'mouse', 'b':'lizard', 'c':'fish'},{'a':'hen', 'b':'pony', 'c':'frog'}]
list_2 = [{'x':'goat', 'y':'mouse', 'z':'horse'},{'x':'horse', 'y':'hen', 'z':'tiger'},{'x':'bee', 'y':'fly', 'z':'toad'}]

unique1 = unique_values_from_list(list_1)
unique2 = unique_values_from_list(list_2)

print(unique1)
print(unique2)
intersection = unique1.intersection(unique2)
print(intersection)
```

Where my results from this would be:

```
unique1: {'fish', 'cat', 'frog', 'dog', 'lizard', 'hen', 'pony', 'bird', 'mouse'}
unqiue2: {'goat', 'fly', 'horse', 'hen', 'toad', 'mouse', 'tiger', 'bee'}
intersection: {'hen', 'mouse'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_values(list_of_dict):
    a = set()
    for a_dict in list_of_dict:
        a.update(a_dict.values())
    return a

print(get_values(listA).intersection(get_values(listB)))
```

maybe?